# Can't restart Postgres on OSX Mavericks - 'Operation already in progress'?

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks

I stopped Postgres on my OSX Mavericks system (using `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`, which appeared to shut down cleanly) and now I can't restart it.

```
~ $ psql -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

There seem to be no running Postgres processes...

```
~ $ ps auxwww | grep postgres
anna            78131   0.0  0.0  2432772    648 s004  S+   12:31pm   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

But when I try to start it, I get the message 'Operation already in progress'.

```
~ $ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist: Operation already in progress
```

I've seen other answers suggesting I should delete the `postmaster.pid` file, but I can't see any file by this name:

```
~ $ sudo find / -name postmaster.pid
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
~ $
```

Does Postgres have a startup log, and if so where could I find it?

Comment: Well, I cured this by restarting, but I still don't know what caused it, or any other way to fix it...

Comment: This problem persists for me across restarts.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tell if something is listening to the Postgresql port with

```
netstat -an | grep -i listen | grep 5432
```

(if your port is 5432)

Then you can tell what is listening by using:

```
lsof -i :5432
```

If nothing is listening on whatever port you set your postgresql instance too listen to, then it isn't running. (for whatever reason)  You should double check your postgresql.conf, your pg_hba.conf, and look in pg_log at the log files for errors.

If you are listening on a non-standard port you may need to use the "-p" psql option to set the port.  If you are listening on your hostname, but not localhost, you may need to set the "-h" option.

ie:

```
psql -U postgres -h 10.1.23.4 -p 12345
```